Bound for $\cos(nx)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$
This concerns proving a  bound for $\cos(nx)$ in terms of  $\cos(x)$, namely the following inequality:
$$
f(n,x) = \cos^{2 n}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^n(x) \cos(n x) \ge 0  
$$
for all $x$ and all positive integer $n$.
Numerically this holds for large selections of $n$.  The maximum of $f(n,x)$ grows  slowly with $n$, exceeding 1 at $n=3$,  exceeding 2 at $n=6$,  exceeding 3 at $n=15$, and obviously never reaching 4 since this is a general  upper bound to $f(n,x)$.
To prove the inequality, the expansions of $\cos(nx) $ can be used. This works, since $\cos(n x)$ can always be expanded in terms of $\cos(x)$. Here are the first  cases:
\begin{align}
& f(1,x) = \cos^{2}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^2(x) = 0\\
& f(2,x) = \cos^{4}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^2(x) (2\cos^2(x) -1) = 3 \cos^2(x) (1 - \cos^2(x)) \ge 0  \\
& f(3,x) = \cos^{6}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^3(x) (-3 \cos(x) + 4 \cos^3(x)) = \\
& \qquad \qquad  \cos^2(x) (1 - \cos^2(x)) (7 \cos^2(x) + 1)\ge 0 
\end{align}
Now this is getting increasingly involved as $n$ increases. Replacing $y = \cos(x)$, all results can be reduced to proving  that a polynomial in $y$ of degree $2 n$ is nonnegative in the range $[-1 \; 1]$.
How can it be generalized?

A proof (sketch). The approach is similar to this.
For $n = 3$, the inequality is true by directly verifying.
In what follows, assume that $n\ge 4$.
WLOG, assume that $\cos x \ge 0$ (if $\cos x < 0$, letting $y := \pi - x$, the inequality becomes
$\cos^{2n} y + \cos^2 y - 2\cos^n y \cos ny \ge 0$ and $\cos y > 0$).
Furthermore, we assume that $x \in [0, \pi/2]$.
We split into two cases.
(1) $0 \le x \le \frac{3}{n}$
Using $\cos nx \le \cos x$, we have
$$\cos^{2 n}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^n(x) \cos(n x)
\ge \cos^{2 n}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^n(x)\cdot \cos x$$
$$= (\cos^n x - \cos x)^2 \ge 0.$$
(2) $\frac{3}{n} < x \le \pi/2$
It suffices to prove that
$$\cos^{2 n}(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \cos^n(x) \ge 0.$$
Letting $w := \cos x$, it suffices to prove that, for all $0 \le w \le \cos \frac{3}{n}$,
$$w^{2n-2} + 1 - 2w^{n-2} \ge 0.$$
We can prove that $\cos \frac{3}{n} \le 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}$ for all $n\ge 4$, by using
$\cos u \le 1 - \frac12u^2 + \frac{1}{24}u^4$ for all $u \ge 0$. Thus, it suffices to prove that, for all $0 \le w \le 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}$,
$$f(w) := w^{2n-2} + 1 - 2w^{n-2} \ge 0.$$
We have, for all $0 \le w \le 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}$,
$$f'(w) = 2w^{2n-3}[(n-1)w^n - (n-2)]
< 0$$
where we use the fact that (using Bernoulli inequality)
$$(n-1)w^n - (n-2) 
\le (n-1)(1-7/(2n^2))^n - (n-2) < 0.$$
Thus, it suffices to prove that $f(1 - 7/(2n^2)) \ge 0$, or
$$\left(1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{2n-2} + 1 - 2\left(1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n-2} \ge 0,$$
or
$$\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}} - \left(1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n-1} \right)^2 \ge \frac{28n^2 - 49}{(2n^2 - 7)^2},$$
or
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}} - \left(1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n-1} \ge \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 - 49}}{2n^2 - 7},$$
or
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}} - \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 - 49}}{2n^2 - 7}
\ge \left(1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}\right)^{n-1},$$
or
$$\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}} - \frac{\sqrt{28n^2 - 49}}{2n^2 - 7}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}
\ge 1 - \frac{7}{2n^2}. \tag{2}$$
For $n=4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, (2) is true.
For $n\ge 9$, we can prove (2) by Bernoulli inequality (equivalently $u^v \ge \frac{u}{u + v - uv}$ for $u>0$ and $v\in (0, 1)$).
We are done.
